# how to compute the required column width for the ls multi-columns display?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ls

when ls display a list of files, it display it in columns according to the terminal width, can I know what is the size of each columns?

Comment: Are you asking about how to reproduce the ls output (use `column`) or how to get the column size from ls output?

Comment: @KamilCuk for example if the width of the terminal is 167 columns (i get it by using iotctl, `w.ws_col`),`ls /dev` shows the list of files in 5 columns, but if t i resized the terminal to 89 columns ls show the same `ls /dev` list of files in 2 columns, I want to know how ls determine the number of columns to display in the terminal?

Comment: Get all the filenames; figure out which one is longest, and see how many times it will fut into the console width.

Comment: `ls` is part of Coreutils in Linux. [coreutils "ls" source code filetype:c](https://www.google.com/search?q=coreutils+%22ls%22+source+code+filetype%3Ac)

Comment: @rici in the "sh" the column is a multiple of an 8 space tab, can i do it to reproduce the both displays?

Comment: Sure, why not? Is your question about how to compute the required column width or about how to get the filenames?

Comment: i want to know how to compute the required column width for ls, i will edit the questoin thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a width of W, and having the N files to output. You can do a binary search to find the maximum number of columns.

You can assume 1 column is always possible (a file per line), and that N columns is not possible (technically, it is, when everything can be printed on a single line, but just for visualizing that the binary search applies).

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 12 // Number of files
#define W 80 // Terminal width

int can_be_printed(int *lengths, int columns)
{
    int lines = 1 + (N-1) / columns; // ceil(N / columns)
    for(int i=0; i<lines; i++)
    {
        int w = 0; // For the required line width
        w += lengths[i]; // First column
        for(int j=i+lines; j<N; j+=lines) // For each filename in the same line
            w += 2 + lengths[j]; // 2 is the space between filenames for the output
        if(w > W) // Required width is higher than terminal width
            return 0; // false
    }
    return 1; // true
}

int main()
{
    int file_lengths[N] = {7, 9, 9, 5, 6, 8, 9, 6, 7, 13, 6, 10};
    int low = 1; // Always possible
    int high = N; // Generally, not possible
    while(high - low > 1) // Perform binary search
    {
        int mid = (low + high)/2; // Cut in half
        int ans = can_be_printed(file_lengths, mid); // true or false
        if(ans) // If it's possible with the width mid
            low = mid;
        else
            high = mid;
    }
    int ans;
    if(can_be_printed(file_lengths, high)) // End BS picking the highest that is possible
        ans = high;
    else
        ans = low;
    printf("Maximum number of columns: %d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```